# rails, link_to: Is it possible to include a link in the :confirm option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, confirm

Is it possible to include a link into the string pass to the `link_to` `:confirm` question option?

Something like:

```
str =  "Please press OK to approve license <http://www.url_to_license.com> before downloading the file"

link_to("Download file1", "http://www.urltofile1.com", :confirm => str")
```

I tried many things, but can't get a link to show up in the confirmation dialog, only text.

I apologize if it's a trivial question, I am new to Ruby & Rails.

Answer (score 1):

That `:confirm` option creates a JavaScript alert with the string you pass in.

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to use HTML in a JavaScript alert so I believe the answer is no.

You should take a look at some JQuery plugins to facilitate your problem.

For example - [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/)